# APPCrash error occurs when executing an exe in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: cmd, exe

Running the command attrib.exe -R findstl.exe in CMD prompt,

Following is the error mesage thrown during the execution of findstl.exe file.

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: findstl.exe
  Application Version:  1.0.0.4
  Application Timestamp:    44cf9191
  Fault Module Name:    findstl.exe
  Fault Module Version: 1.0.0.4
  Fault Module Timestamp:   44cf9191
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 000013c2
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.272.7
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: b04d
  Additional Information 2: b04dc616544198a12bf49514ab807c43
  Additional Information 3: d13e
  Additional Information 4: d13e683d29b989e35d17cb31b48913d8

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy   statement offline:
  C:\windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt